# Grid list Angular Material Masonry

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Is it possible to implement a grid masonry with Grid List of Angular Material? Here the documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview Here are other specifications but in IO material: https://material.io/design/components/image-lists.html

So far I have tried this:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="6" fit>
  <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let aviso of avisos | async">
    <div class="border rounded bg-light p-2">
      <span class="font-weight-bold">{{aviso.titulo}}</span><br>
      <span class="small">{{aviso.descripcion}}</span> 
    </div>
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

And the result is this:
[image]

What I want to achieve is this:
[image]

My goal is to have a masonry grid and then I can filter the elements.

Comment: I doubt there is an easy way to implement a fully dynamic masonry using Angular Material Grid. You would have to know what rowspan/colspan to set for each item. By default the grid would align the items in every row to have the same height.

Comment: Any other alternative for angular?

Comment: Try the vertical column approach rather than the horizontal one. you need to generate the boxes by calculations.

example: if you have 60 element and you wanna show them in 6 columns then modify your logic for col="1" and iterate the loops for each 10 items (60/6=10 items per column) and for next column the next 10 element and apply a float left property of CSS in the main mat-grid-list

Comment: @Rohit.007 this is one way to produce something that looks like the masonry layout. However if the height of the items aren't distributed evenly it may look slightly weird.

Comment: yes I could understand, It will always be weird if because a wrapper component will have the same height in the complete row from left to right and the re-generated component below to it will start after the bottom boundaries of the top container. It won't work in the horizontal way.

Comment: I found this approach per column, it's not bad but what I want is a one-by-row approach. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-column-component